Implementing encryption/decryption in Typescript using Web Crypto API
I'm having a security requirement not to send data as plain-text to the server and the credentials shouldn't be visible in the network tab of the browser. I could have used hashing but the catch is we already have old stored passwords with hash and salting applied. Now, not to disturb the old database, I was thinking to simply encrypt the data and decrypt it on server side (node).
Henceforth, I'm trying to use Web Crypto API to achieve the desired outcome.
Below is a simple script I was trying to write before exporting the logic to both client and server environments :
function base64ToArrayBuffer(base64): ArrayBuffer {
    return Uint8Array.from(atob(base64), c => c.charCodeAt(0))
}

function ArrayBufferToBase64(buffer): string {
    return btoa(String.fromCharCode(...new Uint8Array(buffer)));
}

async function encryptString(privateKey: string, publicKey: string, data: string) {

    let params: AesGcmParams = {
        name: 'AES-GCM',
        iv: base64ToArrayBuffer(publicKey)
    }

    let keyImported: CryptoKey = await window.crypto.subtle.importKey("raw", base64ToArrayBuffer(privateKey), "AES-GCM", true, ["encrypt", "decrypt"]);
    let dataInstance: ArrayBuffer = new TextEncoder().encode(data);
    return Promise.resolve(await window.crypto.subtle.encrypt(params, keyImported, dataInstance));
}

async function decryptString(privateKey: string, publicKey: string, data: string) {

    let params: AesGcmParams = {
        name: 'AES-GCM',
        iv: base64ToArrayBuffer(publicKey)
    }

    let keyImported: CryptoKey = await window.crypto.subtle.importKey("raw", base64ToArrayBuffer(privateKey), "AES-GCM", true, ["encrypt", "decrypt"]);
    let dataInstance: ArrayBuffer = new TextEncoder().encode(data);
    return Promise.resolve(await window.crypto.subtle.decrypt(params, keyImported, dataInstance));
}

// Key for encryption/decryption process
let PRIVATE_KEY: string = 'Fdz2z54vAwIjq0tginHyzgyL62q+f4sBlMi5IOOXJ7c=';
let PUBLIC_KEY: string = btoa(String.fromCharCode(...window.crypto.getRandomValues(new Uint8Array(12))));

// Password to be encrypted before being sent to server
let password: string = "Test@123";

(async () => {

    let encrypted_data: string = ArrayBufferToBase64(await encryptString(PRIVATE_KEY, PUBLIC_KEY, password));
    console.log(encrypted_data);

    let decrypted_data: string = ArrayBufferToBase64(await decryptString(PRIVATE_KEY, PUBLIC_KEY, encrypted_data));
    console.log(decrypted_data);

})();



I'm able to encrypt the string stored by the password variable but not able to decrypt it.Getting following error message :
Promise {<pending>}
VM98:33 FSWTBSgdQNVgYOelgRpU5JZm/4G0TRynIyr2jg==
VM98:36 Uncaught (in promise) Error
await (async)
(anonymous) @ VM98:36

Also, attaching screenshot for details not pasted under logs:

Need help to understand the root cause of this error alongwith the fix I can add to the script to successfully encrypt/decrypt some data.

Incase if someone's aware of a library that I can easily use on both client/server side, that would also be appreciated as an answer.


All those return Promise.resolve(await ... are wrong, it should just return the crypto calls. Although all of this is just security theater, if you have the client-side encrypt the messages it's trivial for anyone to decrypt them as well.

your deciphering issue is because you are decrypting the base64 version of the encrypted data, which of course is not the actual encrypted data you received from encrypt

you probably want window.crypto.subtle.decrypt(params, keyImported, base64ToArrayBuffer(data) - and you don't need let dataInstance: ArrayBuffer = new TextEncoder().encode(data); in decryptString either

You should post the solution in a separate answer. That's the SO paradigm.

return Promise.resolve(await p) === return Promise.resolve(p) === return p usually you want to await if you have a promise and you need the value. But you want to use Promise.resolve() to make sure you have a promise. Using both is nonsense - you wait for a promise to resolve to a value, to wrap it back to a promise. Async functions already return promise anyway, so they'd do the promise wrappi9ng for you anyway.

Below is the script that worked for me as per inputs provided from the community:



    function base64ToArrayBuffer(base64: string): ArrayBuffer {
        return Uint8Array.from(atob(base64), c => c.charCodeAt(0))
    }
    
    function ArrayBufferToBase64(buffer: ArrayBuffer): string {
        return btoa(String.fromCharCode(...new Uint8Array(buffer)));
    }
    
    async function encryptString(privateKey: string, publicKey: string, data: string) {
    
        let params: AesGcmParams = {
            name: 'AES-GCM',
            iv: base64ToArrayBuffer(publicKey)
        }
    
        let keyImported: CryptoKey = await window.crypto.subtle.importKey("raw", base64ToArrayBuffer(privateKey), "AES-GCM", true, ["encrypt", "decrypt"]);
        let dataInstance: ArrayBuffer = new TextEncoder().encode(data);
        return window.crypto.subtle.encrypt(params, keyImported, dataInstance);
    }
    
    async function decryptString(privateKey: string, publicKey: string, data: string) {
    
        let params: AesGcmParams = {
            name: 'AES-GCM',
            iv: base64ToArrayBuffer(publicKey)
        }
    
        let keyImported: CryptoKey = await window.crypto.subtle.importKey("raw", base64ToArrayBuffer(privateKey), "AES-GCM", true, ["encrypt", "decrypt"]);
        return window.crypto.subtle.decrypt(params, keyImported, base64ToArrayBuffer(data));
    }
    
    // Key for encryption/decryption process
    let PRIVATE_KEY: string = 'Fdz2z54vAwIjq0tginHyzgyL62q+f4sBlMi5IOOXJ7c=';
    let PUBLIC_KEY: string = btoa(String.fromCharCode(...window.crypto.getRandomValues(new Uint8Array(12))));
    
    // Password to be encrypted before being sent to server
    let password: string = "Test@123";
    
    (async () => {
    
        let encrypted_data: string = ArrayBufferToBase64(await encryptString(PRIVATE_KEY, PUBLIC_KEY, password));
        console.log(encrypted_data);
    
        let decrypted_data: any = new TextDecoder().decode(await decryptString(PRIVATE_KEY, PUBLIC_KEY, encrypted_data));
        console.log(decrypted_data);
    
    })();



